# How to fix accessibility Issue for 2 forms having same fields in one Page

Tags: html, accessibility

I have 2 forms on one page having the same fields and labels. When I run accessibility check, it runs into an issue saying

```
Control labels should be unique on a page or be close to text providing context.
Controls with the same visible label need extra context (such as a heading) near the control to explain the differences between the fields. Note that the aria-label does not set the visible label.
```

Reference Link - https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/rules/acchtmlformcontrolduplicatelabel/

The fields have unique `for` and `id`

FORM 1

```
<div class="form-field__item form-field__item--text">
  <input id="whitepaper_signup_first_name" class="input form-field__input input--text" name="firstName" type="text" required="">
  <label for="whitepaper_signup_first_name" class="form-field__label form-field__label--dynamic">First name</label>
</div>
```

FORM 2

```
<div class="form-field__item form-field__item--text">
  <input id="homepage_lead_form_first_name" class="input form-field__input input--text" name="firstName" type="text" required="">
  <label for="homepage_lead_form_first_name" class="form-field__label form-field__label--dynamic">First name</label>
</div>
```

Is there a way with `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`?

Comment: One quick question, do these forms also perform the same action (i.e. are they exact duplicates on functionality such as two "quick contact" forms). If you can give a tiny bit of context as to whether the whole forms are identical or not  (or just a couple of the fields) I can help you fix this issue.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Just a couple of fields are identical HTML-wise. Form submit to different places. The tool which throws this issue is PowerMapper FYI.

Comment: I think you're looking at the issue to fine-grained. Yes, it's clear what to enter in the fields, but not at all to which ends. What are the two forms accomplishing? I bet providing a close heading or legend will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error appears to be more of a UI best-practice, as opposed to a WGAG failure. The idea is that the user needs to be able to differentiate between what you're asking for in each field.

If you are asking for the first name of the same person in both inputs, then there's nothing you need to do here and you can ignore the warning. If not, maybe you should update both labels to be more descriptive.

When navigating in forms mode, screen readers will not read any text around an input field. This includes headings and any adjacent text that's not part of the label element. For this reason, it's important that each label accurately describes what the user is expected to enter.

Comment: The fields describe exactly what the user needs to enter when using a screen reader. The issue occurs as an AA Level Issue with the PowerMapper tool.

Comment: If you're asking the user to enter their own first name in each field, then it's probably fine. The error that PowerMapper is throwing is related to WCAG 2.4.6, which requires that "each label makes the component's purpose clear." If you have done that, then everything should be good. PowerMapper (or any automated accessibility tool) will throw a lot of false positives, because they're just algorithms, and they can't parse complex content like a human can. Automated tools are just starting points for looking at accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

The advice to distinguish the accessible names seems to go beyond WCAG 2.1 Success Criterion 2.4.6.

However, if you want to prevent this tool from making this complaint, then you can accomplish that by changing the labeling mechanism. It is currently a `label` element. You can change it to an `aria-labelledby` attribute on the `input` element. That allows you to chain more than one element’s text content together as the label. Then one part of each label can be an element whose text content describes the form itself. That form-level label can be referenced by the `aria-labelledby` attribute of each control in the form.

If you address this issue in that way, you will still leave another accessibility flaw to be addressed. When you ask a user for the user’s first name, you are creating an input that is subject to WCAG 2.1 Success Criterion 1.3.5. To satisfy that criterion you can add an `autocomplete="given-name"` attribute to the `input` element.